# 2006 Mazda 3 blown fuse 53 washer fluid pump, how to find short?

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, mazda-3, windshield-washer, short

My washer fluid pump fuse 53 keeps blowing when I turn the ignition key. I bought a live wire checker and can operate it as per instructions. Can someone help point me in the right direction with checking the wires given my context? Where do I start? I read something about the ?relay? being the probable culprit but I'm clueless. Check from the fuse to the relay?

Aside (probably irrelevant): 2 out of 7 times that I replaced the fuse, the pump did work but next time I turn the key off and on (just electrical, not engine) the fuse blows.

Comment: The fuse blows without activating the switch? any signs of water intrusion? pooling? I don't think there is a washer relay on your car just a fuse, switch, motor and some wiring.

Comment: yes, i don't activate the switch, I just put the key in and turn it to activate the electricals (not starting the engine) and it blows the fuse. I replace the pump motor already. I am guessing that it's a fault before the switch now. My wire checker arrives tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the wiring diagrams, it makes sense that Fuse #53 blows if there is a short.

I would start by unplugging the washer motor, and see if a new fuse remains whole after turning the ignition on.  A simple way to isolate the problem to a shorted washer pump motor.

If that isn't the case, the following diagrams should help:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's a fault before the switch...um is there an easy way for me to figure out how to locate that? Excited to get my wire checker in the mail tomorrow.